# Remove function from list already created using radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the jQuery I am using to collect the user inputs and put into a table below the input box. I am not trying to allow users to remove their name from the list using a radio button and a remove name function. That being said the counter should also be updated when a name is removed. Any ideas?

```
    var counter = 0;
    var wCounter = 0;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#register").click(function(){
            counter++;

            if(counter === 7){
                var warning = "Sorry, but this RoyTalk is completely full!";
                alert(warning);
            }
            else if(counter > 3){
                wCounter++;
                var name = $("#name").val();
                $("#waitList").append('<input type="radio" />'+wCounter+'- '+name+'<br>');
            }
            else {
                var name = $("#name").val();
                $("#regList").append('<input type="radio" />'+counter+'- '+name+'<br>');
            }
        });
        $("#remove").click(function(){
            //need help here
        }
    });
```

Here is the html I am using to get the users to input their name and then submit.

```
<p>Enter your name and click register to reserve your place at the latest RoyTalk!</p>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<span class="regBtn"><button type="btn" id="register">Register!</button></span><button type="btn" id="remove">Remove Name</button>
<br><br>
<table class="regTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Registered</th>
        <th>Waiting List</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="regList"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="waitList"></div>
        </td>   
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Use ==,  counter == 3. single equals is assignment

Answer (score 2):

Single = is for assignment and == for comparison.

```
if(counter == 3){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

mistake is `if (counter = 3)`

`=`  is used for assignment

use `if (counter == 3)`

`==` is used for comparison

Answer (score 1):

check your if condition

```
if (counter == 3) {
    // true condition 
} else {
   // false  condition 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) The basic assignment operator is equal (=), which assigns the value of its right operand to its left operand.

2) A comparison operator compares its operands and returns a logical value based on whether the comparison is true. The operands can be numerical, string, logical, or object values.

**Equal (==)   Returns true if the operands are equal.**

you should use **comparison** for solving your problem.

`if (counter = 3)` should be `if (counter == 3)`

Answer (score 0):

Others have already given a correct answer, but I figured I'd elaborate a bit on assignment vs condition.

**counter = 3** will *set* the counter variable to equal 3

**counter == 3** will *compare* counter to the value of 3

**counter === 3** will *compare* counter to the value of 3 **and** the same value type (in this case 3 is a number, so counter would also have to be a number).

Check out this easy guide to JS comparisons - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp